# Userid not found in seperate file's list

Tags: python, bots, discord

This is a python discord bot I'm trying to get to work. There is a seperate file called users.json where the data is being saved, however the userid, experience and level isn't being updated but repeatedly added.

Tried printing out the ID its comparing at several points, they all show the same id.
Started from scratch a few times but same persistent issue.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as g:
        users = json.load(g)

    await update_data(users, message.author)
    await add_experience(users, message.author, 5)
    await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel)

    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

async def update_data(users, user):
    if not user.id in users:
        users[user.id] = {}
        users[user.id]['experience'] = 0
        users[user.id]['level'] = 1
```

And the result in users.json:

```
{"162634647XXXXXXXXX": {"experience": 5, "level": 1}}
```

Expected results: The data (experience, level) gets updated
Actual results: The same data is put in twice

Comment: Kind of a side-note: you're loading your db (the json) on *every* message?  Might be a logic issue, use `not in` instead of `not x in`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Yes it does load on every message, tried `not x in` and `not in`, both didn't work

Comment: Where is the duplication happening?  Don't you get an Error raised when you try to have duplicate keys in the JSON?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 It does give me an error `[json] duplicate object key`. It duplicates the same string like this: `{"162634647XXXXXXXXX": {"experience": 5, "level": 1}}` twice and then it stops because of the duplicate

Comment: Could more than one message come in and get handled at once?

Comment: @CraigMeier It can handle more than one message, trying it with a buddy at the same time but as soon as a duplicate gets in its game over

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like multiple `on_message` calls are being handled at the same time, so that the JSON is being written to the file twice.

If you have some protection against multiple messages from the same user coming in (e.g. some kind of ack for each message), then you can probably get away with just locking the parts where you're opening the file. Otherwise, the whole `on_message` body will need to be in a critical section to prevent things from getting into an inconsistent state.

The other possibility is that if your keys are not strings, you could be running afoul of the fact that JSON keys are always strings, so the round-trip to JSON doesn't preserve non-string dictionary keys (e.g. `{42: 'foo'}` encodes to `{"42": "foo"}`, which decodes to `{'42': 'foo'}`). If that's the case, it's probably easiest to just use string keys, although it's also reasonable to cast to string to dump to JSON and parse to int on load from JSON.

Comment: I'm testing in a closed environment sending a message with a good amount of delay, It looks like it can't compare the `user.id` or can't find it for some reason

Comment: @MirroredStance Hmm... is `user.id` a string or something else?

Comment: `user.id` is actually `message.author.id` which will always result a large number like so `"162634647XXXXXXXXX"`